# Is there a way to add a custom filter using a color / image?

Tags: html, canvas, html5-canvas

I'm currently using TOAST UI for HTML canvas , is there a way to add a custom filter using a color / image ?

Comment: Custom as in? What have you currently? It seems there are a few built in filters available with variable customizations available: http://nhn.github.io/tui.image-editor/latest/tutorial-example02-useApiDirect

Comment: @Kaiido yes, do you know if there is way turn on the tint filter with a given color and leave it on all the time ?